# code prints out extra data

Tags: c

The code prints out a table showing the values of 1+x, x, and log(1+x).  However at the top there are 3 extra columns with the numbers 1.0, 0.0, and 0.0.  Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  double x;
  printf("(1+x) \t (x) \t  log(1+x)");
  for(x=0.0; x<=1.05;x+=.05)
  {
    printf("%f %f %f \n",(1+x),(x),log(1+x));
  }
  system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: You forgot a `\n` somewhere.

Comment: You are starting at x=0, those are the values at x=0.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to insert a line break after `[...] log(1+x)`

Correcting the line

```
printf("(1+x) \t (x) \t  log(1+x)");
```

to

```
printf("(1+x) \t (x) \t  log(1+x)\n");
```

should do the job

Comment: Wow, I had a major brain fart there.  Thank you!